# Is It necessary to make each strategy's volatility almost equal before solving weight when constructing a risk parity portfolio? Or use other model?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk-parity

Say I want to construct  a portfolio consisting of different trading strategies (but trades same pool of assets) with cross-sectional varying volatility. It makes me feel uncomfortable since the one with greater volatility always gets less weight throughout the whole period of sample which makes the weights not fully diversified among high vol ones and low ones. So, is it necessary to make each strategy's volatility almost equal before solving weight when constructing a risk parity portfolio? Or use other model (pls suggest some other models)?